# Error mysqli_query()

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Muchachos tengo este error en mi código y nose porque es
Una vez le doy al botón de buscar se genera el error, la idea es que en el campo al escribir un nombre y darle enviar me muestre lo que estoy buscando como si fuera un buscador
quedo atento a sus respuestas
gracias!!
hay un segundo campo que es el que se encuentra en la parte de arriba del botón de enviar, pero ese aún no le he puesto alguna función en específico hasta ahora lo único que me está fallando es el primer buscador [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí les dejo el código que tengo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Avanced</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body background="Img/User1.gif" background-size="cover"> 

  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-danger">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">LIST OF GAMES FOR ADVANCED</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <style> 
    body {background: ("User1.gif" );
    background-size: cover;
    }
  </style>

  <a href="Profile_User.php"><img src="Img/Back22.png" width="15%" height="11%"
    style="position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(220%, 90%)"> 
  </a>
  
  <?php //Llamada a la base de datos
  include("base_datos.php") ?>

  <!-- buscador -->

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="col-12">

        <div class="mb-3">

            <label class="form-label">Palabra a buscar</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="buscar" name="buscar">

            <label class="form-label">Palabra a buscar instantaneo</label>
            <input onkeyup="buscar_ahora($('#buscar_1').val());" type="text" class="form-control" id="buscar_1" name="buscar_1">

        </div>
        <button  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="buscar_ahora($('#buscar').val());">Buscar</button>

        <div class="card col-12 mt-5">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div id="datos_buscador" class="container pl-5 pr-5"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>

  <div class="container p-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container p-4">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>   
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <table class="table table-bordered border-primary table-hover">
          <thead>     <!-- Columnas de inidices -->
            <tr bgcolor="aqua"> 
              <th>IdJuego</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Categoria</th>
              <th>Caracteristicas</th>
              <th>Consola</th>
              <th>Lanzamiento</th>
              <th>Imagen</th>
            </tr>
          </thead> <!-- Columnas de los datos  -->
          <tbody>
            <?php //Consulta a la BD tabla juegos_lista para listar los datos en la tabla de la interfaz de user_advanced
                $query = "SELECT * FROM juegos_lista";
                $result_juegos = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_juegos)){ ?>
                      <tr bgcolor="white">
                        <td> <?php echo $row['idJuegos'] ?> </td>
                        <td> <?php echo $row['nombre'] ?> </td>
                        <td> <?php echo $row['categoria'] ?> </td>
                        <td> <?php echo $row['caracteristicas'] ?> </td>
                        <td> <?php echo $row['consola'] ?> </td>
                        <td> <?php echo $row['añoLanzamiento'] ?> </td>
                        <td><img height="30px" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['imagen']) ?>"></td>
                      </tr>
              <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function buscar_ahora(buscar) {
        var parametros = {"buscar":buscar};
        $.ajax({
        data:parametros,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Buscador.php',
        success: function(data) {
        document.getElementById("datos_buscador").innerHTML = data;
        }
        });
        }
     //   buscar_ahora();
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el código de buscador.php

```html
<?php include("base_datos.php");



$buscardor=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM juegos_lista WHERE nombre LIKE LOWER('%".$_POST["buscar"]."%') OR tema LIKE LOWER ('%".$_POST["buscar"]."%') "); 
$numero = mysqli_num_rows($buscardor); ?>


<h5 class="card-tittle">Resultados encontrados (<?php echo $numero; ?>):</h5>

<?php while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($buscardor)){ ?>


<p class="card-text"><?php echo $resultado["nombre"]; ?> - <?php echo $resultado["tema"] ?></p>


<?php } ?>

tiene menú contextual
```